# me.level works on prompt but not on script

Tags: python-2.7, steam

module downloaded from https://github.com/smiley/steamapi

```
>>> import steamapi
>>> username = "mastabomba"
>>> steamapi.core.APIConnection(api_key=“API”, validate_key=True)
<steamapi.core.APIConnection object at 0x10beb8910>
>>> steamapi.user.SteamUser(userurl=username)
<SteamUser "mastabomba" (76561198041685201)>
>>> me = _
>>> me.level
8
```

testapi.py sample

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import steamapi
username = "mastabomba"
steamapi.core.APIConnection(api_key=“API”, validate_key=True)
steamapi.user.SteamUser(userurl=username)
me = username
me.level
```

when executed

```
$ ./testapi.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testapi.py", line 7, in <module>
    me.level
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'level'
```

can someone point me where I had done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscore `_` is holding the result of the last executed statement, so without digging very deeply, I think you should change your code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import steamapi
username = "mastabomba"
steamapi.core.APIConnection(api_key=“API”, validate_key=True)
me = steamapi.user.SteamUser(userurl=username)
me.level
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the main cause.